# How to layout animations of sublayers of a CALayer

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, appkit, caanimation

I have a layer with a sublayer. The sublayer has its position animated. Now I want the animation of the position to scale appropriately when the bounds of the superlayer change, e.g. the width of the superlayer doubles so the distance of the animation doubles as well.

I've been trying to do this by overriding the superlayer's `layoutSublayers()` function and in it replacing the old animation with a new scaled one. However adding a new animation to the sublayer appears to cause my application window to freeze the application for a few seconds before starting the animation to switch into fullscreen. Any other scaling of the window works just fine.
The following code is what I am currently using:

```
override func layoutSublayers() {
    guard self.image != nil else { return }

    if var currentPosition = self.imageLayer.presentation()?.position {
        let relativeCurrentPosition = CGPoint(x: currentPosition.x / self.oldBounds.width, y: currentPosition.y / self.oldBounds.height)
        currentPosition = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width * relativeCurrentPosition.x, y: self.bounds.height * relativeCurrentPosition.y)

        var targetPosition = (self.direction == .AtoB) ? self.positionB : self.positionB
        let relativeTargetPosition = CGPoint(x: targetPosition.x / self.oldBounds.width, y: targetPosition.y / self.oldBounds.height)
        targetPosition = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width * relativeTargetPosition.x, y: self.bounds.height * relativeTargetPosition.y)

        if self.direction == .AtoB {
            self.positionA = currentPosition
            self.positionB = targetPosition
        } else {
            self.positionB = currentPosition
            self.positionA = targetPosition
        }

        let newPanAnimation = self.panAnimation
        newPanAnimation.duration = self.animationDuration - (CACurrentMediaTime() - self.timeAtImageStart)
        self.imageLayer.add(newPanAnimation, forKey: "pan")
    } else {
        CALayer.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.imageLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2, y: self.bounds.height / 2)
        }
    }

    CALayer.performWithoutAnimation {
        self.imageLayer.bounds = self.originalImageLayerBounds
    }
}
```

That is why I was wondering, what would be considered the right way to do this or if maybe I already am on the right track and there simply is a different issue.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you post the code that you currently have?

Comment: I added it to my original question.